# How do I compare each element in table to another table from database one by one efficiently?

Tags: java, mysql

I am helping for a friend, we're trying to compare several tables retrieved from database and check if each element equals to the elements from other tables.

Let's say there are several tables like these.

```
Table A
+---------+---------+---------+
|  Col1   |  Col2   |  Col3   |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 |
| Value 7 | Value 8 | Value 9 |
+---------+---------+---------+
Table B
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   Col4   |   Col5   |   Col6   |   Col7   |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Value 10 | Value 11 | Value 12 | Value 13 |
| Value 14 | Value 15 | Value 16 | Value 17 |
| Value 18 | Value 19 | Value 20 | Value 21 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

We want to compare each value from `Table A` to every value in `Table B`. So starting with `Value 1` from `Table A` is compared to `Value 10` from `Table B`, then `Value 1` is compared again to `Value 14`, then `Value 18`, then move to the next column to be compared with `Value 11`, `Value 15`, and so on to `Value 21`. After `Value 1` is compared with every element in `Table B`, we compare `Value 4` to every value in `Table B` all over again.

There'll be definitely a lot more tables, hundreds even, to be compared to each other. My friend has written some code, which actually works, but said to be really slow and inefficient.

```
// GET TABLE QUERY
table = md.retrieveTableName();
// ITERATE EACH TABLE
for (int a = 0; a < n_tables; a++) {                
    colName = md.retrieveColumnName(table.get(a));
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from " + database + "." + table.get(a));
    // ITERATE EACH COLUMN IN TABLE A
    for (int b = 0; b < colName.size(); b++) {
        colType = md.retrieveColumnType(table.get(a), colName.get(b));
        rlSet = ps.executeQuery();
        // ACCESS NEXT DATA
        while (rlSet.next()) {
            Element1.add(rlSet.getString(colName.get(b)));
            // ITERATE ALL EXISTING TABLES
            for (int d = 0; d < n_tables; d++) {
                if (a != d) {
                    ps2 = conn2.prepareStatement("select * from " + database + "." + table.get(d));
                    colName2 = md.retrieveColumnName(table.get(d));
                    // ITERATE EACH COLUMN FROM TABLE
                    for (int c = 0; c < colName2.size(); c++) {
                        rlSet2 = ps2.executeQuery();

                        while (rlSet2.next()) {
                            Element2.add(rlSet2.getString(colName2.get(c)));

                            if (Element1.get(Element1.size()-1).equals(Element2.get(Element2.size() - 1))) {
                                System.out.println("Same value");
                                        // DO SOMETHING HERE

                                    } ......
```

My friend wants to compare the data in each column to one certain column, because there's some calculation involved in that one. I wonder if there's a more concise way to do this? I haven't been using Java in a long time and I could only guess that there's a better way to do this?

I'll add more details if requested. Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks like a maze, but what is more important is that I don't think you gave us enough information to write a SQL query.  SQL tables are modeled after unordered sets of data.  Whatever order you perceive is not really there in general unless you impose it via an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: We want to compare each value - and do what?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am not sure I understand correctly, but I don't think the order really matters here. `ORDER BY` is used to order rows in a table, and here order isn't really a problem.

Comment: @P.Salmon basically, if we find more than two equal data in different tables, there'll be some equation for that one, if not equal then nothing happens. I hope that answers your question?

Comment: You wrote generic names like `Table A` and `Col1`. Do you want to check every table in your database or some specific ones, where you know the table and column names? And why do you have "hundreds of tables"? What exactly are these tables for and why do you want to compare some values between them on some random looking check? Please edit your question to elaborate on your problem, it sounds like a XY problem or like a bad database design.

Comment: @Progman My friend is doing some semantic-related work and it includes checking each data with one another (there'll be some semantic-related treatment for the data once it's discovered to be equal). So no, it's not a common query just to retrieve data, it has to check each element, if you understand what I mean. And about the hundreds of tables case, that's the number of tables that we have to work on.

Comment: @AnnaRG Where did the tables come from? Is it possible to normalize them so you might be able to run a "simple" JOIN query on the table(s) to find the duplicates? Please edit your question with the new informations and explain more in detail about the "semantic-related work".